# Determining if a list of objects contains both a property value and returned value from method call

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a basic blackjack game via text. At the moment, I am trying to determine if the two cards dealt to the player, which are held in a list, are an Ace and a card with a value of 10 (A face card or a 10). I have a method set up to return the numerical value of the cards. Is there a way to search the list of cards and determine if the list contains a card with the property `Card.Kind = "Ace"` and call the method `CardValue()` and see if any `Card` objects have a value of 10?

This is the code for my `Card` class

```cs
public class Card
    {
        public String Suit { get; set; }
        public String Kind { get; set; }

        public int CardValue()
        {
            int value = 0;
            switch (this.Kind)
            {
                case "Jack":
                case "Queen":
                case "King":
                    value = 10;
                    break;
                case "Ace":
                    value = 11;
                    break;
                default:
                    value = int.Parse(this.Kind);
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

and my `Player` class that contains the list of player cards.

```cs
public class Player
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

        public Player()
        {
            Cards = new List<Card>();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use an `if` statement to find if an Ace is in the list of cards held by the player

```cs
if (player.Cards.Contains(new Card { Kind = "Ace" }))
{

}
```

but I cannot figure out how to call the `CardValue()` method and if either of the cards in the list have a value of 10.

Comment: You can have a dictionary with card name as key and numerical value as value. Then just pass it the card name/kind and get the value, or in the current scenario, you should change your CardValue method to take in Card Kind and give out value.

Comment: `if (player.Cards.Any(c => c.Kind.Equals("Ace"))) { }`. You could use an `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq Expressions for this.

```
if (player.Cards.Any(x => x.Kind == "Ace" ))
{

}
```

and again for `CardValue()`

```
if (player.Cards.Any(x => x.CardValue() == 11 ))
{

}
```